# How to connect Django's built-in username and password fields to user-defined html input tags

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have used a pre-defined html template for my login form and I have tried to connect the django's standard/built-in username and password fields namely `{{ form.username }}` and `{{ form.password }}` to the input fields of the html template. It works fine, but it populates the fields with `None` in both of the username and password fields everytime a user is redirected to the login page.

When using the {{ form.username }}`and`{{ form.password }}` template tags, they are populated with valid user credentials. Is this normal or I am missing something here?

Here is the code that I have tried to use an input field instead of Django's built-in username and password field:

```
<!-- username input field-->
<div class="group">
    <label for="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}" class="label">Username</label> 
    <input id="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}" maxlength="100" name="{{ form.username.html_name }}" value="{{ form.username.value }}" type="text" class="input">
</div>

<!-- password input field-->
<div class="group">
    <label for="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}" class="label">Password</label>
    <input id="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}" maxlength="100" name="{{ form.password.html_name }}" value="{{ form.password.value }}" type="password" class="input">
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple template filter will do the trick: `default_if_none`

```
<input ... value="{{ form.username.value|default_if_none:"" }}" .../>
```

When the input value is an empty string the browser will automatically populate them with proper values.